# php variable to ajax data

Tags: php, ajax

I have edited my code and it goes something like this and it is not working.. Please help me..

```
<?php
    $variable = "krishna";
?>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:{
            variable:<?php echo $variable; ?>
        },
        success:function(msg){
            $("#val").html(msg);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="val"></div>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['variable'];
?>
```

thank you all

Comment: you can use echo, if its not dinamically; cant you generate the variable with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `echo` statement inline with the javascript. Because PHP executes on the server all the PHP processing will be done by the time the javascript runs.

```
<?php
$variable = "php";
?>

<script>
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"",
data:{
variable:"<?php echo $variable; ?>"
},
success:
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"",
data:{data:'<?php echo $data; ?>',data1:'<?php echo $data1; ?>'}
success: function(data)
{   }
});
</script>
```

You can add any number of varibles using **data{data1:data1, data2:data2, data3:data3}** and it's stand like **{variablename:value}**

Comment: Not proper syntax, values must be quoted.

Comment: For posting code that does not work as an answer, yes. Since removed after fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: 'var=<?php echo $variable;?>',
            success: function(){

            }
       });
</script>
```